# Putting jQuery Script at the End of the Queue in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce, flexslider

The problem started when I realized that Woocommerce's Flexslider edits one of the DIV tags and it gives the width of 1600%. I didn't want this attribute. That's why I prepared a code to fix it along with some other attributes:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){         
        $( '.slides' ).css("width", "");
        $( '.slides' ).css("margin-left", "");
        $( '.slides' ).css("margin-right", "126px");        
    });
```

I saved this code in a file named `final.js` inside the theme's js directory. But I haven't been able to make it work!
I read an article about enqueue-ing (if there's such a verb) the scripts, [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). I tried and it seems like, the script will be included inside the header among the other scripts. But no matter if it's at the top or the bottom of the other ones, it won't work!

I tried to put it at the bottom of the page without using the enqueue method.
All I could get from my efforts is adding `margin-right` to the class `slides`. This is not enough. Which ever code is changing this class, is firing after my custom script and doesn't let it happen.

Do you have any suggestions to make this this thing work?
Here's the [link to site](http://ashrafii.com/product/cartier-6022/) if you want to have a look (should look for: `<div id="carousel" class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">`).

Thanks!

Comment: don't need script for this, set rules in a stylesheet

Comment: Charlie, the attribute is added via jQuery in-line. So the HTML will be like: <ul class="slides" style="width: 1600%; margin-left: 0px;"> after it's loaded completely. You just can't change in-line CSS using stylesheet.

Comment: Actually you can if you override using `!important`

Comment: Ahh... interesting! Thanks Charlie! Nice workaround!

Answer (score 1):

It's look like your slider are load after your script, according to Flexslider doc, you should try to put your code on the callback when slider are loaded like:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        start : function() {
            $( '.slides' ).css("width", "");
            $( '.slides' ).css("margin-left", "");
            $( '.slides' ).css("margin-right", "126px");   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it gives me some error. You know, wordpress has its own jQuery statements. So, we can't use $ like other places. I have to use: jQuery(window).load(function($) { but it seems like it's not working either. Can you find out what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with WooCommerce. Flexlider is being added by your theme: Avada.

If you make the flexslider script a dependency for the `final.js` script then `final.js` will be loaded after flexslider. And/or if you run your `wp_enqueue_scripts` function on a later hook then you will also likely load `final.js` after flexslider.

I don't know what the "handle" is for flexslider in Avada, nor do I know exactly the path to your custom script, but as an example:

```
function so_28782012_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'final', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/final.js', array('flexslider'), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_28782012_enqueue_scripts', 99 );
```

Comment: Thanks Helga. I used your code. It adds final.js at the bottom of the page. And I assume the 'flexslider' statement holds the script to run after the flexslider. But somehow, it runs before the slider and the attributes are overwritten by it. So, it's still not working this way. Maybe it's not flexislider that provides these properties.

Comment: Well my code is just to get your script to come after Flexslider. Whether that ultimately achieves what you need is another matter. I think Flexslider giving one div (or possibly UL) element is part of its design. You can see it happening in the [demo](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/). Maybe rephrase to explain exactly what you need to do, and/or just stick with CSS.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the css is way too easier. Thanks for the code though.